What's the translation of shitcoin in French?
https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shitcoin.asp:

The term shitcoin refers to a cryptocurrency with little to no value or no immediate, discernible purpose. The word is a pejorative term often used to describe altcoins or cryptocurrencies developed after Bitcoin became popular.

What's the translation of shitcoin in French? Google Translate didn't help.

I would hazard that, like 99% of portmanteau tech words that didn't exist 5 years ago, Google Translate won't help because there is no French translation. You have to go the extra mile and figure out how French tech articles periphrased it, or use the English term directly.

I can't figure out (w/o using google at least) a translation for bitcoin, let alone shitcoin. I would use un bitcoin merdique.

Bitcoin est un nom propre et n’est donc pas traduit en français. Shitcoin n’a pas d’équivalent non plus. Par contre, la traduction de cryptocurrency est cryptomonnaie alors pour traduire shitcoin je suggère cryptomerde.

Coin != Bitcoin

Shitcoin
Désigne une crypto-monnaie qui n'a aucune base technique sérieuse, qui ne repose sur rien de concret et qui ne sert qu'à spéculer ou arnaquer les débutants. https://cryptoast.fr/lexique/ Pas de traduction "officielle".

If the expression crypto monnaie de singe does not exist, the time is ripe to invent it. Or crypto daube.

Shitcoin in French is shitcoin. Shitcoin on Le Journal du net, Clubic and lots more... Likewise memecoin is memecoin in French.

Note that "shitware" has the time-honored translation merdiciel in computer jargon. I'm sure the French-speaking Canadian grok the word on 1st hearing it. The problem is what to make of "coin".

Le terme est récent et péjoratif, donc il ne faut pas s'attendre à une traduction officielle. On peut s'inspirer de la prononciation péjorative de bitcoin : bite-coin ([bit.kwɛ̃], en nasalisant fortement la deuxième syllabe pour bien marquer la moquerie)1. Certains distinguent peut-être « le Bitcoin [bit.kɔjn] » (prononcé à l'anglaise) d'« un bite-coin [bit.kwɛ̃] » (prononcé à la française). Sinon on peu chercher d'autres variantes sur ce thème péjoratif. Un trou-d'coin, peut-être ?
Si on veut être plus francophone et moins vulgaire, cryptomonnaire de singe (jeu de mot avec monnaie de singe) comme suggéré par François Jurain est attesté (et pas seulement pour Apecoin, si si ça existe).
1 Source : je travaille dans la sécurité informatique y compris la cryptographie, et dans ce milieu, on n'aime en général pas les cryptomonnaies.

Bitcoin itself can be pronounced pejoratively in French: if you try to pronounce it as written as if it was a French word, i.e. [bit.kwɛ̃], it sounds like “cock-quack”, though sadly the “quack” part is only a duck's cry and not a swindler. So you could distinguish « le Bitcoin [bit.kɔjn] » (approximating the English pronunciation) from « un bite-coin [bit.kwɛ̃] » (with a derisively exaggerated French accent). Otherwise you can try continuing on the same pejorative theme. Maybe « trou-d'coin » (evoking asshole)?
If you want to build a purely French expression and avoid vulgarity, cryptomonnaire de singe as suggested by François Jurain (deriving from monnaie de singe, i.e. fake money, Monopoly money) is attested (and not only for Apecoin).

En fait, ce « cock-quack » est quelque peu arbitraire :  « cock-corner » or « cock-nook » pourraient venir facilement à l'esprit.

@LPH Quand on dit “coin” d'un ton moqueur, ça fait penser au canard, pas à l'angle.

Cette expression "une traduction officielle" est toujours problématique à mon avis...

J’ai entendu quelqu’un (homme parisien d’une quarantaine d’années, classe moyenne-supérieure) utiliser le terme caca-monnaie à l’oral.
Pour traduire shitcoin, ce terme me paraît plus fidèle que les autres suggestions. Il rend bien le registre de langue : shit est vulgaire (ou a minima très familier) en anglais, mais en français merde est carrément grossier alors que poubelle, étron, etc. sont neutres. Enfin, il est assez facile à comprendre pour quelqu’un qui ne l’aurait jamais entendu.
Je vois deux inconvénients à ce terme :

tout comme son équivalent anglais, il n’y a pas de référence explicite à l’aspect « crypto » ; il est donc à réserver à un contexte où celui-ci est explicite, sinon l’auditeur pourrait s’imaginer qu’on parle d’une monnaie sans valeur, comme le Deutschmark de la république de Weimar.
je ne le trouve nulle part sur internet, je suppose que c’est une invention de la personne que j’ai entendue (mais pour un néologisme sans traduction fermement établie, ce n’est pas forcément rédhibitoire).


I see the term "crypto-poubelle" used on a few webpages: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crypto+poubelle%22

Example:

Le Bitcoin est-il une crypto poubelle?



If you follow the link from the page results you can see it all leads to this man who wrote: « Votre investissement en crypto-monnaie peut très vite se transformer en crypto-poubelle  ». It's clear that the crypto-poubelle is the container in which lies the valueless  crypto-monnaie, and not the cryptocurrency  itself.

@None this is incorrect, e.g. the second link from the result page uses crypto-poubelle to designate a single cryptocurrency: "Le Bitcoin est-il une crypto poubelle?" https://i.sstatic.net/BHbbTVhz.png

The sentence I quote comes from the very article of which you give the title. We probably don't understand the article in the same way...  Same word construction as crypto-album: the album in which you put your crypto-timbres.

@None we don't understand differently. The author uses that term in two different ways.

If you search for shitcoin  in a French corpus you can see it is not translated (as already mentioned in comments). Journal du coin. Cryptoactu, Quelles sont les meilleures shitcoins aujourd'hui ?, etc... And you can even find the definition of shitcoin in French (e.g.).
